# Can't Find Cordova Plugin Documentations

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have been facing this issue for some time and it started to drive me crazy. Plugin references on the official page doesn't show all capabilites, function and constant definitions and enough examples. I collect information about these functions from other websites. But where do they get those definitions? For example description for cordova-plugin-file on the official website is simply useless. Can anyone enlighten me about this?

Comment: The sourcecode on github is the best documentation.

Comment: @David I'll give it a try thanks.